# Некоректная робота bootstrap-sass

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, sass

**Подскажите почему меню навигации перекриваєт верхнюю часть страници ? Не могу понять . От што у меня вишло :**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**А должно бить так :**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Я установил gem:**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js :**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Создал файл app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:**

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                          "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb :**

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("ruby_on_rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Я просто добавил**

> nav-tabs

**в 
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
 и все зароботало :**

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```